# Get 2D output from the embedding layer in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I have a X_train with size of (2, 100). I want to use the 2*50 first of the data, and use the second 2*50 of this matrix as the input of embedding and convert that to a matrix with size 2*3.

I read a lot about the embedding layer in pytorch, however I did not understand it well. I don't know how to get a 2*3 as the output of the embedding layer. Could you please help me with that? Here is a simple example.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

X_train = np.random.randint(10, size = (2, 100))

X_train_notmbedding = X_train[:, 0:50] # not embedding  (2,50)
X_train_mbedding    = X_train[:, 50:100] #embedding  (2, 50)
X_train_mbedding = torch.LongTensor([X_train_mbedding])
embedding = nn.Embedding(50, 3)
embeding_output = embedding(X_train_mbedding) # I want to get a embedding output as (2,3)

#X_train_new = torch.cat([X_train_notmbedding, embeding_output], 1) # here I want to build a matrix with size (2, 53)
```

Comment: What does you input signify? and why it should return 2, 3. From the input you have 50 embedding and each embedding returns a vector of 3. so the return [50, 3] is correct, and for the batch (of 2) it is [2, 50, 3].

Comment: The thing that I want, I want to shrink a vector of size 50 to a vector of size 3. When I chose 'nn.Embedding(1, 3)', it gives me an error. For a batch of 2, i. e (2, 50) I want to build (2,3) with embedding. Not (2,50,3).

Comment: Not how Embedding layer works. To reduce/train 50 parameters to 3, you might as well use a Fully connected layer (after normalizing the input). This looks like a design issue rather than an NN issue. What does a int vector size of 50 denote? Is this a length of a 50 word/character in a statement or something else entirely?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Actually, I have a vector or KWH consumption, and weekday, and holidays and ID. The 50 which I want to feed to embedding, are weekday, holidays and Id. Kind of (0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2, ....).

Comment: OK. taking another step back ... what are you trying to infer? Do you want to see what the KWH consumption trend is?

Comment: Yes exactly. My goal is to predicting the KWH. Here is one link which I saw that they use the embedding for a same problem https://medium.com/bcggamma/a-better-way-forecasting-with-embeddings-8f45e7065f2b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion, it looks like your understanding of Embeddings is not accurate.

1. Only use 1 Embedding for 1 feature. In your example you are combining dates, ids etc. in 1 Embedding. Even in the medium article, they are using separate embeddings.
2. Think of Embedding as one-hot encoding on steroids (less memory, data co-relation etc.). If you do not understand one-hot encoding I would start there first.
3. KWH is already a real value not categorical. Use it as a linear input to the network (after normalization).
4. ID: I do not know what ID denotes in your data, if it is a unique ID for each datapoint, it is not useful and should be excluded.

If the above does not make sense, I would start with a simple network using LSTM and make it work first before using an advanced architecture.